# How to find Grand Total in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subtotal

I developed a SSRS tabular report using below query

```
select Department, 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), sum(si.GrossPrice) / 100.0) gross 
from SaleItem si, Sale sa
where GrossPrice != 0 and sa.SaleID = si.SaleID
and sa.StartDate between '2015-01-03 04:00:01' and '2015-08-04 04:00:00'
group by Department 
order by Department
```

and it give the o/p like below screen

[image]

Now I need to show the grand total of the amount. How can I do it. I done grouping of the items in first column then include sub total but that give me subtotal after each line of the item. I need grand total of entire amount.
I am new to SSRS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Design` tab of the rdl, in the `Tablix` right click on the `Department` cell or `Gross` cell and select `Insert Row` and then `Outside Group - Below`.

You'll have a new row outside the group.

In the cell below `Department`, type text `Total`.
In the cell below `Gross`, add the expression `=Sum(Fields!gross.Value)` which will give you the grand total.

Comment: forget to tell one thing `=Sum(Fields!gross.Value)` didn't worked...`[Sum(gross)]` worked..except that everything i followed your answer..once again thanks for the help